# Test code fails for Answer and Reply Insert in a customer portal site

Tags: salesforce

I want to run a test script which test for Question and replies; but it shows following error when I insert a reply to a question.

INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, null: [CommunityId]

Here is the code snippet

```
        User u2 = new User(abcd );insert u2;
       User u3 = new User( sfsadfas); insert u3;


Question question = new Question();
                question.Title = 'Test';
                question.Body = 'Test';
                question.CommunityId = 'asfsadfsadfasdfsa';
                insert question;                  
                Id questId ;
                questId = question.Id;   
            System.debug('questId --->'+questId );  
                Reply reply1 = new Reply();
                //reply1.Name = 'replyquestion11';
                reply1.Body =  'reply no 1 ques 1';
                reply1.QuestionId = question.Id; 
                //reply1.CommunityId = 'fasdfsadfsadfsadf';   
                System.debug('reply1--->'+reply1);        
                insert reply1;

            Test.startTest();  
            System.RunAs(u2)
            {    Reply reply2 = new Reply();
                //reply1.Name = 'replyquestion11';
                reply2.Body =  'reply no 2 ques 1';
                reply2.QuestionId =  question.Id;      
                 System.debug('reply2--->'+reply2);            
                insert reply2;          //Insert Fails here
            }
```

Can any one help me with this. I want to user diff users to post reply to the question..

Answer (score 0):

By default the insert of question and reply1 were executed with your permissions (you have  a System Administrator profile, right?).
Then you execute runAs(*some fresh user, probably got assigned a standard license and Standard User profile*) and he can't see the Question record created by sysadmin.

1. Does the other user (you'de be best explicitly specifying his profile) has rights to at least Read the Questions object.
2. Does he have either View All on this object or maybe there's sharing setting for public readonly access.

Read up on [security model](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/managing_the_sharing_model.htm), then decide to apply sharing settings or at least manually share the question record in the unit test...